# Synchronize data between two postgres database

Tags: database, postgresql, scripting, synchronization

Data from client database is fetched and stored in our local database. both database is postgres. I want to sync these two databases such that data entered in client database is stored in destination database too.

Comment: 1) [Logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html). 2) [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response.. .but do we have some method wherein we dont have to make any change to source database since its client based. we can only access the data from there.

Comment: You obviously did not read the information at the links provided. Hint: 2.

Answer (score 1):

simple solution is to make full dump:

```bash
pg_dump --data-only -p 5432 mydb > tmp/db_dump.sql
psql mydb < tmp/db_dump.sql
```

though it is not very performant, since it downloads all the data each time